# Big Query Regex: Match all from a set of words

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(column_with_text, r'(\bword1\b|\bword2\b|\bword3\b)') as matching_words` for extracting any of the 3 words anywhere in the text, regardless of the order and case.

For the following text:
`here random word here word2 or here word1 random words`
it extracts word1 and word2 which is nice.

However, with another query, I want to extract those words if all of those three words appear in the text, again regardless of order and case. I am trying like:
`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(column_with_text, r'(\bword1\b)(\bword2\b)(\bword3\b)')`.

For the following text:
`here random word here word2 or here word1 random words` it should return nothing since the text does not contain word3. But it should return all the three words if the text would be: `here word3 for example random word here word2 or here word1 random words`

This throws the following error in Big Query:

*Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function for this - for example

```
create temp function regexp_extract_only_if_all(text string, regexp string) as ((
  select if(array_length(arr) = cnt, arr, null) from 
  (select regexp_extract_all(text, r'' || regexp) arr, array_length(regexp_extract_all(regexp, r'\|')) + 1 cnt)
));
with your_table as (
  select 'here random word here word2 or here word1 random words' column_with_text union all
  select 'here word3 for example random word here word2 or here word1 random words'
)
select column_with_text, 
  regexp_extract_only_if_all(column_with_text, r'\bword1\b|\bword2\b|\bword3\b') as extracts
from your_table
```

with output

[image]